# Chrome Extension - Change default_icon for active tab only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a simple extension that requires the default_icon to change depending if a JS variable exists in a page or not. It's as simple as that, at least this feature.

I managed to change the picture on each page load with this condition, but I would like to go further and have the picture changed for all loaded tabs in the user's browser, whenever the user changes the tabs he's focusing on.
I'm having trouble trying to have the default_icon be changed for the active tab only.

Would anyone know how I should proceed to make it so ?
(I'm still a beginner in writing Chrome Extensions)

My content.js :

```
if (test == "OK") {
    // Setting OK Icon
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "Existing"});
}
else if (test == "NOK") {
    // Setting NOK Icon
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "Not existing"});
}
```

My background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "Existing" ) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"OKicon.png"});
    }

    if( request.message === "Not Existing" ) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"NOKicon.png"});
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you should take a look at the [`chrome.browserAction.setIcon` documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon).

> integer   (optional) `tabId`
>
> Limits the change to when a particular tab is selected. Automatically resets when the tab is closed.

Just what was needed! Now, the tab ID is [reported in the `sender` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "Existing" ) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path:"OKicon.png",
            tabId: sender.tab.id
        });
    }

    if( request.message === "Not Existing" ) {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path:"NOKicon.png",
            tabId: sender.tab.id
        });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! That was it ! 
I tried to work with that tabId but I had no idea what to put in it.
Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there. All you would need to do is wrap the logic you have in the content script as a callback to the `window focus` event.

```
window.onfocus = function(){
  if (test == "OK") {
      // Setting OK Icon
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "Existing"});
  } else {
      // Setting NOK Icon
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "Not existing"});
  }
}
```

When user changes focus the `background` script will receive the runtime message from the `context` script and change the extension icon accordingly.

Comment: Actually, it's directly supported by `setIcon`, see my answer